# IdlError: Type not found

Tags: anchor, testing

I am trying to test an initialize function that takes in as parameter an object rather than just one value:

```
    pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<InitializeAuction>, args: CreateAuctionArgs) -> Result<()> {
        let state = &mut ctx.accounts.state;


        state.end_auction_at = args.end_auction_at;
        state.state = AuctionState::Idle;

        Ok(())
    }
```

with CreateAuctionArgs:

```
#[derive(Clone, BorshSerialize, BorshDeserialize, PartialEq)]
pub struct CreateAuctionArgs {
    /// End time is the cut-off point that the auction is forced to end by. See AuctionData.
    pub end_auction_at: UnixTimestamp,
    /// Token mint for the SPL token used for bidding.
    pub token_mint: Pubkey,
    /// Authority
    pub authority: Pubkey,
    // / The resource being auctioned.
    pub resource: Pubkey,
    /// Add a tick size increment
    pub tick_size: u64,
}
```

My test code:

```
const AUCTION_SEED = anchor.utils.bytes.utf8.encode("auction");

describe("auction", () => {
  // Configure the client to use the local cluster.
  anchor.setProvider(anchor.Provider.env());

  const program = anchor.workspace.Auction as Program<Auction>;
  const _wallet = anchor.getProvider().wallet;
  const _resource = new PublicKey(PublicKey.default);

  it("Is initialized!", async () => {
    // Add your test here.
    const [auctionPDA, _] = await PublicKey
    .findProgramAddress(
      [
        AUCTION_SEED,
        program.programId.toBuffer(),
        _resource.toBuffer()
      ],
      program.programId
    );

    const tx = await program.methods
    .initialize({ 
      end_auction_at: 0,
      token_mint: new PublicKey(PublicKey.default),
      authority: _wallet.publicKey,
      resource: _resource,
      tick_size: 1
    })
    .accounts({
      state: auctionPDA,
      resource: _resource,
      treasury: new PublicKey(PublicKey.default),
      signer: _wallet,
      system_program: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId
    })
    .signers([
      _wallet
    ])
    .rpc()

    console.log("Your transaction signature", tx);
  });
});
```

When running this (`anchor test`) it fails with:

```
IdlError: Type not found: {"name":"args","type":{"defined":"CreateAuctionArgs"}}
    at Function.fieldLayout (/Users/danielpavel/web3/ssoc-2022/SSoS-Daniel-Pavel/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/coder/borsh/idl.ts:94:19)
    at /Users/danielpavel/web3/ssoc-2022/SSoS-Daniel-Pavel/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/coder/borsh/instruction.ts:114:22
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/danielpavel/web3/ssoc-2022/SSoS-Daniel-Pavel/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/coder/borsh/instruction.ts:113:38
    ...
```

What's wrong with this code? I've seen example in anchor book [Tick Tack Toe](https://book.anchor-lang.com/anchor_in_depth/milestone_project_tic-tac-toe.html) implementation that does exactly that to pass in an object as parameter. Check out the Tile param in play function:

```
pub fn play(ctx: Context<Play>, tile: Tile) -> Result<()> {
...
}
```

Comment: Speculation: Is `CreateAuctionArgs` in your IDL? If so, what fields does it have? I'm wondering if Anchor might have changed the field names to camel case eg `endAuctionAt`, `tokenMint`, which is what it does with fields on accounts, events, etc.

Comment: There are 2 `CreateAuctionArgs` refs, both defined under `instruction` as such: `"args": [{"name": "args","type": {"defined": "CreateAuctionArgs"}}]`

Comment: Is the actual structure not in the IDL? I'd have expected it would be, but I don't have experience doing what you're doing.

Comment: Nope, it's not.

Answer (score 1):

Reading this [post](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/issues/651) helped.

The structure `CreateAuctionArgs` was not being generated inside the IDL.

The issue: I was decorating it with attributes `BorshSerialize` and `BorshDeserialize` instead of `AnchorDeserialize` and `AnchorSerialize`.

Thank you Callum M for pointing out that `CreateAuctionArgs` might not be inside the IDL.

Comment: After fixing this, another issue emerged where it did not recognized the `Unixtimestamp` type, throwing the same error (`IdlError: Type not found: {"name":"endAuctionAt","type":{"defined":"UnixTimestamp"}}`). 

This post helped (https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/issues/1632)